# Plotting two histograms of a continuous variable, with bars next to each other instead of overlapping

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot two histograms in one plot, but the way these two groups are distributed makes the histogram a little hard to interpret. My histogram now looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
hist(GROUP1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2), breaks=100, freq=FALSE,xlab="X",main="")  # first histogram
hist(GROUP1, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/2), breaks=100, freq=FALSE , add=T)  # second
legend(0.025,600,legend=c("group 1","group 2"),col=c(rgb(1,0,0,1/2),rgb(0,0,1,1/2)),pch=20,bty="n",cex=1.5)
```

Is it possible to plot this histograms, with the bars of the two groups right next to each other, instead of them overlapping? I realize that that might add some confusion, since the X-axis represents a continuous variable... Other suggestions of how to make this plot in more clear are of course also welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could misuse `barplot` for it:

```
multipleHist <- function(l, col=rainbow(length(l))) {
    ## create hist for each list element
    l <- lapply(l, hist, plot=FALSE);

    ## get mids
    mids <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, function(x)x$mids)))

    ## get densities
    densities <- lapply(l, function(x)x$density[match(x=mids, table=x$mids, nomatch=NA)]);

    ## create names
    names <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, function(x)x$breaks)))

    a <- head(names, -1)
    b <- names[-1]
    names <- paste("(", a, ", ", b, "]", sep="");

    ## create barplot list
    h <- do.call(rbind, densities);

    ## set names
    colnames(h) <- names;

    ## draw barplot
    barplot(h, beside=TRUE, col=col);

    invisible(l);
}
```

Example:

```
x <- lapply(c(1, 1.1, 4), rnorm, n=1000)
multipleHist(x)
```

[image: multiple histograms in one plot]

**EDIT:**
Here is an example to draw a x-axis like the OP suggested. IMHO this is very misleading (because bins of a barplot are not continuous values) and should *not* be used.

```
multipleHist <- function(l, col=rainbow(length(l))) {
    ## create hist for each list element
    l <- lapply(l, hist, plot=FALSE);

    ## get mids
    mids <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, function(x)x$mids)))

    ## get densities
    densities <- lapply(l, function(x)x$density[match(x=mids, table=x$mids, nomatch=NA)]);

    ## create names
    breaks <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, function(x)x$breaks)))

    a <- head(breaks, -1)
    b <- breaks[-1]
    names <- paste("(", a, ", ", b, "]", sep="");

    ## create barplot list
    h <- do.call(rbind, densities);

    ## set names
    colnames(h) <- names;

    ## draw barplot
    barplot(h, beside=TRUE, col=col, xaxt="n");

    ## draw x-axis
    at <- axTicks(side=1, axp=c(par("xaxp")[1:2], length(breaks)-1))
    labels <- seq(min(breaks), max(breaks), length.out=1+par("xaxp")[3])
    labels <- round(labels, digits=1)
    axis(side=1, at=at, labels=breaks)

    invisible(l);
}
```

[image: multiple histograms in one plot (modified x-axis)]

Please find the complete source code on [github](https://github.com/sgibb/sgtools/blob/master/R/multipleHist-functions.R).

Comment: "You could misuse barplot for it" best quote of the day +1

Comment: Just to be a wet blanket on @TylerRinker 's comment -- what the OP asked for is in fact a bar plot.  A histogram is a very specific type of chart, and you would find it rather difficult to interpret data when overlaying two histograms.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is it possible to get an x-axis with ticks and continuous labeling of the ticks, as the example plot in the opening post?

Answer (score 8):

Rather than messing about with overlapping histograms, what about:

1. Have two histograms in separate panels, i.e.

   ```
   par(mfrow=c(1,2))
   d1 = rnorm(100);d2 = rnorm(100);
   hist(d1);hist(d2)
   ```
2. Or, use density plots

   ```
   plot(density(d1))
   lines(density(d2), col=2)
   ```
3. Or use a combination of density plots and histograms

   ```
   hist(d1, freq=FALSE)
   lines(density(d2), col=2)
   ```